# Second request throws exception since upgrading to Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I have an application which is exhibiting weird behaviour since upgrading Rails from 3.1.12 to 3.2. The first request works fine, but the second (and subsequent) request fails with:

```
undefined method `_callback_before_1579' for #<Noodall::FormResponse:0x00000006513cf8>
```

The application deals with `Noodall::Form` and `Noodall:FormResponse` objects. A `Noodall::Form` has many responses.

This happens when trying to save a response object [like this in the controller](https://github.com/noodall/noodall-form-builder/blob/develop/app/controllers/noodall/form_responses_controller.rb):

```
@form_response = @form.responses.build(params[:form_response])
@form_response.save
```

The app uses Mongo Mapper is create keys dynamically for a model.

```
many :responses, :class => Noodall::FormResponse, :foreign_key => 'noodall_form_id' do
  def build(attrs={})
    doc = klass.new
    apply_scope(doc)
    doc.set_up_keys!
    doc.attributes = attrs
    @target ||= [] unless loaded?
    @target << doc
    doc
  end
end
```

You can see all the [code here on GitHub](https://github.com/noodall/noodall-form-builder/blob/develop/app/models/noodall/form.rb).

Is there anything in Rails 3.2 that could be causing this? I'm at a loss to know what to do next?